# PyQt4 newbie: QColumnView automatically set column width with custom model

Tags: python, qt4, pyqt, pyqt4

I'm a Qt4 newbie, but I can't seem to find the information I need in the manuals or on the net:

I have implemented a very simple data model, with a data() method responding to DisplayRole, ToolTipRole and DecorationRole inputs.  I have not implemented a headerData() method (but I tested one as listed below).

When I use the model with a QColumnView, the columns are of fixed size.  The width of the various nodes in my data model vary considerably, so I am looking for a way for QColumnView to automatically set the width of the column according to the data returned from the data() method.

I cannot find any "setResizeMode()" method which is available on other kinds of views.  I tried returning a QSize() from data() with an input role of SizeHintRole with something like this:

```
            text = str(node.display_name())
            value = QtCore.QSize(len(text)*10,20)
```

Strangely the height seems to be adjusted, but the width of the columns is still constant.

I tried implementing a headerData method that looked like this:

```
def headerData(self, index, orientation, role ) :
    ret = QtGui.QHeaderView()
    ret.setResizeMode( QtGui.QtHeaderView.ResizeToContents )
    return ret
```

But that had no effect; I'm sure that the header view needs to be manipulated and set in some other way, but I'm having trouble finding out what that is.

Can someone point a newbie in the right direction?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can rearrange width by calling setColumnWidths method.
For instance, try to connect model signal to such slot and you are done.
Slot can calculate actual width from model and prepare list for setColumnWidths.

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand your explanation. Can you give a line or two of code?  I'm aware of the setColumnWidths() method, but I am not aware of a means of calculating a "tight fit" for the columns with which to feed that method.  Thanks.